# Large database of mathematical constants

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Is there a repository of billions of mathematical constants, computed say with 15 digits of accuracy, so that when you find a number, say $5.859874482$, it tells you that it matches the first $9$ digits of (in this particular example) $\pi+e$? Ideally, some online platform where you enter your number and it shows the closest constant in the database. I know OEIS.org has a bunch of constants, but I am not sure how to do this type of search on this platform. Sometimes a Google search will work, but most of the time it does not work. Incidentally, if you search for "$5.859874482$" on Google, you actually get the answer! This would be very useful to discover new relationships or put an exact value on some series or integrals that you computed with 15 digits of accuracy.

Comment: This sounds like an inverse symbolic calculator, one of which can be found here: http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple different ones in different format.

- The [ebyte.it list of Mathematical Constants and Sequences](http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/constants/MathConstants.html) has some basic ones, and if you format your number properly, you can ctrl-f for it
- [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) seems closer to what you want, where you can put in the number and it comes up with all kinds of expressions and constants that it matches.  Try the [search for "3.14"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.14) and see at the bottom of the results it highlights how many decimals of Pi it matches. Also, here is a [search for your number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5.859874482%20) as well.
- For [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), what is the problem exactly? Try [this search](http://oeis.org/search?q=5.859874482&sort=&language=english&go=Search) to see your requested number match the expamsion of pi + e. If you need more control, there are [search api details](https://oeis.org/eishelp2.html).